# Symfony2: does fetch="EAGER" create a join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this mapped property inside my `product` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="products", indexBy="id", fetch="EAGER")
 *
 */
protected $groups;
```

I wonder, my understanding for `fetch="EAGER"` is that it should get the groups once the product is selected, this is what happens but it uses 2 queries whenever i do something like `findBy()` one query to get the `product` and another one to get the `groups`.

Is there anyway to make `findBy()` or other helper methods get the `product` along with its `groups` in one query or the only way is to write a custom repository function and do a `LEFT-JOIN` myself?

**UPDATE**

I tried multiple solutions and endup overwriting the `findBy()` function something like:

```
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $q = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u, g')
    ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit );

    foreach ($criteria as $field => $value)
    {
        $q
            ->andWhere(sprintf('u.%s = :%s', $field, $field))
            ->setParameter($field, $value)
        ;
    }

    foreach ($orderBy as $field => $value)
    {
        $q->addOrderBy(sprintf('u.%s',$field),$value);
    }

    try
    {
        $q = $q->getQuery();
        $users = $q->getResult();
        return $users;
    }
    catch(ORMException $e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1- Can i use `fetch="EAGER"` to make findBy return the `product` along with its `groups` in one query

2- If not then is there any case that i use `fetch="EAGER"` with many-to-many entities without killing performance

3- Is overriding the findBy is a good approach? any drawbacks?

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, it should not execute 2 queries - that's the whole point of `EAGER` fetching. Now that I think of it, I'm not really sure. I will try this as soon as I get to my dev box...

Comment: @jperovic i tried it with two different project, it's still executing 2 queries. if it's the case i don't see why i would use findBy or findOneBy for entities that has relationships with other entities which it's always about 70% to 90% of the entities in any project.

Comment: IT really looks like that with many to many, fetch=eager is not much usefull, just for curiosity, do you see any diferences if you make the product entity the owning side? (change mappedBy="products" for inversedBy="products")

Comment: @Francesc not at all. i tried both ways and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The FETCH_EAGER mode has it's problems. In fact there is an open request [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1149) to resolve this issue but hasn't been closed yet.

I recommend using a custom repository to fetch the data in the manner you want it.