# Symfony2 + Doctrine: Multiple where conditions using array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity and i'm trying to create the following function inside its repository

```
function customGet(array $criteria)
{
     //WHAT I'm trying to do:
     //SELECT *
     //FROM mytable
     //LEFT JOIN anothoer table
     //WHERE criteria1 = value1 AND criteria2 = value2 ...etc

     $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, g')
        ->leftJoin('u.theOtherTable', 'g');
        //Where here
        ->getQuery();
}
```

How can i do the where clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, g')
        ->leftJoin('u.theOtherTable', 'g');

    foreach ($criteria as $field => $value) {
        $q->andWhere(sprintf('u.%s = :%s', $field, $field))
          ->setParameter($field, $value);
    }

    return $q->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly, is it a good practice to use this to override Doctrine FindBy method ? since i'm having problem with `fetch="EAGER"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421861/symfony2-does-fetch-eager-create-a-join

Comment: You should try to "filter" already on the Join if possible, but besides, this is in my opinion a good practice to write dedicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way if all entity association done correctly

```
function customGet(array $criteria)
    {
         $value1 = $criteria['0'];   //Your expected value
         $value2 = $criteria['1'];   //Your expected value

     $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, g')
        ->leftJoin('u.theOtherTable', 'g');
        ->where('criteria1 = :value1 AND criteria2 = :value2')
        ->setParameters(array('value1'=>$value1,'value2'=>$value2))
        ->getQuery();

   return $q->getResult()
}
```